# Running, rolling, and moving averages

Tags: time-series, terminology

From what I have read, it seems that these three things are the same. What is the difference (if any) between running, rolling, and moving averages?

Comment: In addition to Rob's answer (+1), what *does* matter is "*the window*". Does it roll/move/run *or* does it *expand* from some fixed start point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=moving%20average) define running, rolling, and moving averages as the same thing. Searching the [Wolfram Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=running%20average) returns the same answer. The website [DeskBright](https://www.deskbright.com/), which offers lessons in Excel, has [the same opinion](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/rolling-average-in-excel/).

'Dr. Math' at [The Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128165913/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65639.html) wrote:

> The term "rolling average" is used in the financial community. In statistics and mathematics, the term "moving average" is usually used.